# spring integration dispatcher threads

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Can the below  configuration lead to a mem leak or threads not getting shutdown properly . Is it a good idea to have such a configuration .

```
 <int:bridge input-channel="channel1" output-channel="processingChannel"></int:bridge>

 <int:bridge input-channel="channel2" output-channel="processingChannel"></int:bridge>

 <int:bridge input-channel="channel3" output-channel="processingChannel"></int:bridge>

 <int:bridge input-channel="channel4" output-channel="processingChannel"></int:bridge>

 <int:channel id="processingChannel">     
 <int:dispatcher task-executor="executor"/>
 </int:channel>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no known problems with such a configuration from within the framework. Best thing is to take a thread dump with jstack to figure out what your threads are doing.

Comment: <task:executor id="executor" pool-size="10-20" queue-capacity="25" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" />

Comment: ok thanks. I am not sure you are able to see the full configuration i posted

Comment: <int:bridge input-channel="channel1" output-channel="processingChannel"></int:bridge>

 <int:bridge input-channel="channel2" output-channel="processingChannel"></int:bridge>

 <int:bridge input-channel="channel3" output-channel="processingChannel"></int:bridge>

 <int:bridge input-channel="channel4" output-channel="processingChannel"></int:bridge>
     
     <int:channel id="processingChannel">     
     <int:dispatcher task-executor="executor"/>
     </int:channel> 

<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="10-20" queue-capacity="25" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" />

Comment: for some reason it is not visible in the main description . I have four channels connected via a bridge to the processingChannel.

Comment: You have to have at least 4 spaces before code, especially XML; I edited your question but it still doesn't change my answer; there's nothing in that config that will cause a memory leak or stuck threads in the framework itself.

Comment: Just Gary mentioned it is so hard to understand that this configuration cause a memory leak or some thread locked, just get jStack for threads lock the system or for memory issue get a heap dump with jMap.

Comment: I have already analyzed my application thread dumps and there are no issues . I just posted a question to get some expert opinion on if I have to handle any explicit shutdowns for the threads created by the task:executor here . Thanks . Il take Gary's answer for now :)